# Two sets of topics/words in Topic Modeling

Tags: unsupervised-learning, topic-model, lda, dirichlet

In short, the question is: I have two sets of words per document. I would like to extract two sets of topics per document corresponding to sets of words.

To be more precise:

- Document(d) can be modelled as a union of two sets of words (WordSetA, WordSetB), where WordSetA union WordSetB is all words in (d)
- The goal is to find two sets of topics related to the sets of words (TopicSetA and TopicSetB), where TopicSetA is a mixture of words in WordSetA only (TopicSetB is similar)
- I have the ratio of TopicSetA to TopicSetB per document as an input. for example, if the ratio is 1:1 in a document and the total number of topics per document is 6 so I should get 3 topics of type A and 3 topics of type B

Is there any modification of LDA or HDP that can do this task?